# enable comments in RHandsonTable but disable context menu?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I want to add comments to my rhandsontable but I don't want to enable the context menu (that allows user to add and remove rows, edit comments, etc.). How can I do this?

```
library(rhandsontable)

vt <- mtcars
modrows <- c(3,6,9)
modtext <- LETTERS[1:3]
vttooltips <- matrix(ncol = ncol(vt), nrow = nrow(vt))
vttooltips[modrows, 2] <- modtext

rhandsontable(vt, 
              comments = vttooltips) %>% 
  hot_context_menu(allowRowEdit = FALSE, allowColEdit = FALSE, 
                   allowReadOnly = FALSE, allowComments = TRUE, 
                   allowCustomBorders = FALSE, customOpts = list())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution, thank to @DzimitryM at
https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/334

```
t <- rhandsontable(vt, 
              comments = vttooltips)
t$x$contextMenu <- list()
t
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```r
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

vt <- mtcars
modrows <- c(3,6,9)
modtext <- LETTERS[1:3]
vttooltips <- matrix(ncol = ncol(vt), nrow = nrow(vt))
vttooltips[modrows, 2] <- modtext

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    rHandsontableOutput('table')
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    tbl <- rhandsontable(vt, readOnly=TRUE,
                         comments = vttooltips)
    output$table <- renderRHandsontable(tbl)
  }
)
```

There is more info about combining Rhandsontable and shiny [here](http://stla.github.io/stlapblog/posts/shiny_editTable.html).

Comment: I know how to put it in shiny, but the problem is not a shiny problem it is with rhot directly.

Comment: would you like to clarify your question?

Comment: See question above. I have a rhot. I want to add comments (tooltips for individual cells). To do this you need to enable the context menu (the right click menu for rhot). hot_context_menu() allows you to disable some of the context commands but not all, and I don't really want the context menu, I only want the cell comments.

Comment: so I have  `readOnly=TRUE` in `rhandsontable()`, which disables altering cells while enabling the comment function.  I am not sure what else you want here.

Comment: Sorry I want passive comments only, not user comments.But the right-click menu is still active, giving the impression that users can add and remove rows etc. I do have cells that must be editable so a blanket readOnly=TRUE won't work.